# Check when GPS is active

Tags: android, android-location, android-gps

The idea is simple : when it's GPS available - use gps for geolocation, when it's blinking - use network provider.

`LocationListener`'s  `onStatusChanged` is not triggered anyhow when GPS stops blinking, so I was using `GpsStatus.Listener` and wonderfully when GPS fixed it called `GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_FIRST_FIX`. Great! But if I loose fix and then go back to fix - this event wouldn't be called anymore! Because it's .. well .. first fix only.

And no event was called when GPS lost and started blinking again. How can I trigger such basic things like catching and loosing GPS?

Comment: are you trying to use 2 different lication listeners one for GPS one for Network? if so why not just use the FusedLocation API it does that for you

Comment: yes, 2 listeners, but the idea is to use gps when available and switch to network when gps cannot fix

Comment: yeah so use the FusedLocation API it handles all that for you. https://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html

Comment: Plot twist: Android already handles this for you.

Comment: m0skit0 how's that?